# Trying to group on a column, while selecting all other information with ordering

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I'm having a bit of trouble constructing a query to use the following conditions:

1. Match against an org
2. Sorted by score (desc) and then by handle (asc)
3. Group on the type

So this query is my starting point:

```
select * from social_media_handles where org = '00000001' order by score desc, handle asc;
```

Which will give me the following data ... which I then need to group by type so I'm only pulling out the top matched social_media_handles.

```
   org    |                            handle                             |                   url                   |   type   |      score      | dataset_date
----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+--------------
 00000001 | boathousesw15                                                 | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | twitter  | 500111972000056 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | aspall                                                        | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | twitter  | 500111972000018 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | nathansloane                                                  | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | twitter  | 500111972000018 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | youngspubs                                                    | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | twitter  | 500111972000018 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | pages/the-boathouse-putney/153429008029137                    | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | facebook | 500111972000011 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | putneysocial                                                  | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | twitter  | 500111972000009 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | theexchangesw15                                               | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | twitter  | 500111972000009 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | youngspubs                                                    | http://www.youngshotels.co.uk           | twitter  | 500111970000016 | 2013-10-15
```

Expected output

```
   org    |                            handle                             |                   url                   |   type   |      score      | dataset_date
----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------+-----------------+--------------
 00000001 | boathousesw15                                                 | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | twitter  | 500111972000056 | 2013-10-15
 00000001 | pages/the-boathouse-putney/153429008029137                    | http://www.boathouseputney.co.uk        | facebook | 500111972000011 | 2013-10-15
```

I've tried `group by`, `distinct` and sub-queries, but didn't have much luck. Is there a pattern around this problem?

I am using Postgres and have this problem solved with `distinct on`, but I'm looking for a version which is compatible with different vendors.

Comment: I don't understand how we're defining `top matched social_media_handles` !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry, those with the highest value in the `score` column per `type`.

Comment: Aha, well assuming that Roman Pekar's second solution works with postgres (with a minor correction) then my guess is that that will be fastest.

Comment: @Strawberry I think it depends, if you have 10000 records with type = 'facebook' and you have a proper indexes, then first one will be faster

Comment: OK - I don't know postgres so I can't really comment on that kind of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem comes up frequently on SO, and it usually is given the tag [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) (where *n=1* in your case).

Here are a couple of common solutions that would work in MySQL:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM social_media_handles AS h
JOIN (
    SELECT type, MAX(score) AS score 
    FROM social_media_handles WHERE org = '00000001' 
    GROUP BY type) AS maxh USING (type, score)
WHERE org = '00000001' 
ORDER BY score DESC, handle ASC;
```

The second solution uses no subquery or group-by. It tries to match a row h1 to a hypothetical row h1 with the same `type` and `org`, but with a higher `score`. If no such row h2 exists with a higher score, then h1 must *be* the row with the highest score.

```
SELECT h1.*
FROM social_media_handles AS h1
LEFT OUTER JOIN social_media_handles AS h2
 ON h1.type = h2.type AND h1.org = h2.org AND h1.score < h2.score
WHERE h1.org = '00000001'
 AND h2.score IS NULL
ORDER BY h1.score DESC, h1.handle DESC;
```

Which solution is fastest? It depends. I have had both work better, depending on the size of the dataset, number of distinct types, etc. So you should test both solutions and see what works better for your case.

The CTE solution shown by @Roman Pekar is also good for an RDBMS that supports CTE syntax. Those include PostgreSQL, Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, IBM DB2, and several others.

MySQL and SQLite are the only widely used databases that still don't support CTE syntax.

Comment: +1 for second solution and for mentioning that there's no silver bullet :), I forgot about not exists one. Perhaps I should add to my answer that solutions could work differently if there're duplicates in the original table

Comment: @RomanPekar, right if you have multiple rows that all have the max score per group, then you get more than one row in the result. That's way the CTE solution is best.

Comment: Cheers for making me aware of greatest-n-per-group. It's something I'll have to look into it a lot more.

Answer (score 1):

There're a few methods to do this, all based on 2 ideas. First idea is to get recordset with max score for each type and then join original table to this recordset. Second idea works if you have ranking functions - you just use `row_number()` inside each `type` and then filter out all records with `row_number > 1`

So the first idea could be written like this:

```
select *
from Table1 as T
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from Table1 as TT
        where TT.type = T.type
        having max(TT.score) = T.score
    )
```

or

```
select T.*
from Table1 as T
    inner join (
        select max(TT.score), TT.type
        from Table1 as TT
        group by type
    ) as TT on TT.type = T.type and TT.score = T.score
```

If you have ranking functions, then you can use second idea also:

```
with cte as (
   select *, row_number() over(partition by type order by score desc) as rn
   from Table1
)
select *
from cte
where rn = 1
```

You can easily replace common table expression with subquery:

```
select *
from (
   select *, row_number() over(partition by type order by score desc) as rn
   from Table1
) as a
where rn = 1
```

**update**

One thing to mention - if you have more than one record with, for example, `score = 500111972000056 and type = twitter`, then first solution will return more than one record for type = 'twitter', while second one return one arbitrary row for type = 'twitter'

Also, I forgot to mention third idea (see nice @Bill Karwin answer). I'll just add it here:

```
select *
from Table1 as T
where
    not exists (
        select *
        from Table1 as TT
        where TT.type = T.type and TT.score > T.score
    );
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c0a7/7)</kbd>**